# How to get the URL of the current firefox tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am creating a firefox extension. I want to get the URL of the current "top" firefox tab. How can I access this information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its been a while since i played with XUL, but i think there is a way for you to access the current tab's url/uri. I would suggest you look @ this link for more info. It has a couple of great examples on how to achieve similar tasks... Link: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser)